# Azure database not available for remote Management Studio and VS2013

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Azure database is not available for remote Management Studio run on my laptop and from Visual Studio 2013 Express.

[image: Management connection Problem]

Tracert shows problem
![TracertProblem][20]
[image]
When I connect from azure virtual machine I can connect - I do the same operation.

[image]

I also checked firewall settings.

[image]

Can I ask for a hint?

I changed firewall on azure database - but it doesn't any good. 
[image: Azure Firewall picture]
 Have any of you had such a strange problem? I set up a full range of IP addresses. I set for a laptop and also address the issue.

Visual Studio 2013 has similar problem with connection azure sql
[image: VS can't establish data connection]
 I can publish my web application on azure Web Apps so I am not completly beginner.

Comment: I don't think I can keep replying to you. You are throwing information everywhere: Your question, your (non-answer) answer, and even in comments with links to images. You really need to stop and take some time to learn how to properly ask questions. This isn't a place for you to blast information all over the place, post your user credentials, and ask other users to login to your accounts.

Comment: Can you click on the "Options >>" in your connections dialog and share those screenshots? if you have connected to multiple databases across different servers, one of those configs may have been cached.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with local firewall settings. You must add your local laptop's IP address to the SQL Database server's firewall. Otherwise, you won't be able to make a connection. In `portal.azure.com` you'll see this under the server settings:

[image]

There's also an option to allow all Azure services to access your SQL Database, which is likely what you enabled, since your virtual machine has access. Here's an example with Azure service access granted. Notice the button for adding client IP address, which is what you need to do:
[image]

Comment: Hi David! Thank you for your aanswer.

Comment: Please don't EVER post your credentials on the world wide web! This has likely already been google-cached (and even if you edit/delete your answer, high-rep StackOverflow users may still go back and see revision history). You should change your creds asap. If your database firewall allows Azure services to access it, you just opened your database instance to *every single Azure app.*

Comment: And no, I do not have time to connect remotely into your database.

Comment: HI David! I added all IP adresses. I did everything I could, but the problem remained.

Comment: David! Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

In your first screenshot, click the 'Options' button and set the default database that you want to connect to.

Or

In the "Connect to server" dialog please enter your credential in the following format: USERNAME@DATABASENAME

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Logins are username@databasename.

Comment: I made cleanup. Is ok?